# Checking the validity of a variable before calling the super constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor, extends, super

So I'm writing some code that involves extending a class I have previously written in which files are created and named using a constructor that takes in a name and a size of type long. In that original class, I verified within the constructor that the entered file name contained one "." character but did not require a specific extension on the file. For this new class that I am writing, I am requiring the name's extension be ".mp3".However, my compiler does not like verification before the super constructor.

This is my current code:

```
public class Song extends DigitalMedia{

private String artist;
private String album;
private String name;
private long size;

public Song(String aName, long aSize, String aArtist, String aAlbum){
    super(aName, aSize);
    setArtist(aArtist);
    setAlbum(aAlbum);
}
```

Is there any way to verify that "aName" contains ".mp3" before I create that constructor?

Comment: @J Zane I suggest you to study about constructor calling hierarchy and why its designed in such a way that it is mandatory to call super class constructor first. When we study we should not just digest the facts but should try to find answer as why its like that, what wrong would have happened if it was not like this.  Also I suggest you to study about what happens if exception is thrown from Constructor. I have tried to put a little on these things in my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/42179930/504133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say whether it's the best way to design your program, but you could call a validator method inside one of the `super` arguments:

```
public Song(String aName, long aSize, String aArtist, String aAlbum){
    super(validateName(aName), aSize);
    setArtist(aArtist);
    setAlbum(aAlbum);
}

private static String validateName(String name) {
    if (whatever) {
        throw new Whatever();
    }
    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code execution reaching the  `constructor` implies the object is live and now ready for initialization of its `states` (fields).

Object of a class `A.java` can also be called as an Object of super class of `A.java`. Before class `A.java` initilizes the state, its makes sense the objects inherits the properties and features from the super class. After super class does the initialization , the class `A.java` gets the chance to does is initialization.

Constructor of super class is implicitly called if there is a no parameter constructor present in the super class else you need to call any one of the parameterized constructors of the super class explicitly.

What you wish to do if the condition fails in the `constructor` ? You have option of throwing an exception but still the object is created, you can verify the same by overriding the `finalize()` method and checking the `this` object. You may want to influence the garbage collector by invoking `System.gc()` for the code execution reaching the `finalize()` method sooner.

**proposed solution**
You should validate the parameters of constructor before invoking the constructor. If you want to encapsulate it in your class then you may opt to add a non private static method  (you may wish to name it like `getInstance()`)creating  and returning the object of the class `Song`. You can have your constructor as private in such a case. Note that this will make your class as non extendable, it is simply a design choice.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to enforce your rules via built-in type checking.

You could create a `MediaFormat`:

```
interface MediaFormat { }
```

A `MusicFormat` which implements `MediaFormat`, allowing you to specify which musical formats are supported:

```
enum MusicFormat implements MediaFormat {
    MP3("mp3");

    private final String format;

    MusicFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return format;
    }
}
```

`DigitalMedia` could then be composed of a `MediaFormat`:

```
class DigitalMedia {
    private final MediaFormat format;
    private final String name;

    public DigitalMedia(String name, MediaFormat format) {
        this.name = name;
        this.format = format;
    }
}
```

`Song` could accept a `MusicFormat`:

```
class Song {
    public Song(String name, MusicFormat format) {
        super(name, format);
    }
}
```

This will force users to use whatever is specified in `MusicFormat`, avoiding all those nasty checks. You could then expose a `String` method that returns `name + "." + format`

Comment: I think this is the best alternative. Strong typing gives you the possibility to tackle errors at compile-time whereas the other solutions require handling errors at run-time, which is often more difficult and makes the code more complex. Of course if `MusicFormat` is created from a string, you also need run-time error handling, but this solution allows to separate that concern from song-creation.

Comment: @MickMnemonic It's a constant, no runtime checks needed. The only problem would be if he declared the constant incorrectly, which runtime checks will not help. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Looks like OP is getting the file extension as an input from somewhere, so `MusicFormat.valueOf(inputString)` would need to be handled run-time.

Answer (score 0):

From an inheritance stand-point, a sub-class shouldn't really be more restrictive than it's super class.

But if you want to make the instantiation of the sub-class more restricted, you could make the constructor `private` and provide a factory method that first does the validation.

```
public class Song extends DigitalMedia {

    private String artist;
    private String album;
    private String name;
    private long size;

    private Song(String aName, long aSize, String aArtist, String aAlbum) {
        super(aName, aSize);
        setArtist(aArtist);
        setAlbum(aAlbum);
    }

    public static Song makeSong(String aName, long aSize, String aArtist, String aAlbum) {
        //... validation code
        return new Song(aName, aSize, aArtist, aAlbum);
    }
    ...
}
```

Instead of restricting the type itself, you use encapsulation to enforce the invariant.